# sql performance - query design when fetching from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Ok, premise. Three tables, simple enough for this exercise:

```
table first:
id, name

table second:
id, firstId, secondName

table third
id, thirdName, secondId
```

I want to take all rows in third that have a foreignkey to a row in the second that have a relation to a certain "first" row id.

Typical sql:

```
select t.id, s.id as secondId, t.thirdName, s.secondName from third t 
inner join second s on t.secondId=s.id where s.firstId = X
```

So here is my question:

Would it be faster performance wise, to have a column in third instead that is a foreign key directly to first?

i.e.

```
table third:
id, secondId, firstId, name
```

So that i instead could make the query:

```
select t.id, s.id as secondId, t.thirdName, s.secondName from third t 
inner join second s on t.secondId=s.id where t.firstId = X
```

There are no less joins since i need the data from "second" too, but i'd make the lookup on "firstId" from third rather than second.

Just curious if anybody has any input :)

Comment: No, I don't think it will be much of a difference, if any. It could be slower even. If you were to join `table3` to `table1`, skipping the join to `table2`, yes. (Adding the `firstId` to table3 would mean  a design change, changing the Primary and Foreign Keys of table 2 and 3.)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Well, the premise was that i would need the data from table2. Regarding designchange, yeah well, from a domain theoretical perspective, but i was just discussing in introducing the "firstid" column in "third" from a performance perspective, i.e. duplicating the info. Oh well, i'll keep it as it is i guess :)

Comment: It's certainly an alternative to consider. Table2: adding a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(id, firstid)` and Table3: adding `firstid` and changing the FK to `FOREIGN KEY (secondid, firstid) REFERENCES table2(id, firstid)`. Compound PKs and FKs make joins easier in many occasions. The problem is that some DBMS cannot handle auto_increasing sequences in composite keys and many ORMs cannot handle composite PKs and FKs at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the second way *is* faster, if you re-write your first query as:

```
select t.id, s.id as secondId, t.thirdName, s.secondName from second s
inner join third t on t.id=s.id where s.firstId = X
```

Note the swapped placements of `second` and `third`. With this you will see the exact same performance as your second example, but the `third` table will be smaller because it doesn't have the extra redundant field.

To point out the benefits of not having this field, it's easier to point out what adding an extra redundant field will do to performance:

- consume more disk space
- slow down any table scans because rows will now be *slightly* longer
- update performance will also be *slightly* slower
- among others...

While theoretical, it this overall sounds an awful lot like a premature optimization, you should only be doing this **IF** your existing query is slow (even when doing my above re-write of it), at which point you will get a much better bang for your buck by just improving your indexes.

Comment: Ah thanks, you're right, that would be basically the same question, so there, theoretically, is no point in including the column in table 3. Obviously it also takes up more harddisk space, yeah :) And sure its premature, and i wasn't planning on actually doing it - but you know how it is when you get something in your head!

Answer (score 0):

The surest way to find out is to try it and see.

However, given that you need to join to the second table anyway, I would actually expect it to be a bit slower, since you would have to fetch all records from the table `third` first, and then link each of them to the appropriate record on `second`, rather than fetching the `second` records first and then linking to the `third` records - so you would be retrieving 2*m*n records in the first scenario, and only (m+1)*n records in the second.

Of course, if you didn't need to link to the `second` table, the query would run much faster if it only accessed the `third` table.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed design would be incorrect. There is nothing to guarantee that `third.firstId` matches the `second.firstId` of the parent row.

Correctness is more important than performance!

---

That said, you *might* be able to use identifying relationships and natural keys (as opposed to non-identifying relationships and surrogate keys):

[image]

This is appropriate if `thirdName` does **not** need to be unique on its own, but only in the context of the parent row from the `second` table, and `secondName` does **not** need to be unique on its own, but only in the context of the parent row from the `first` table.

In this scenario, you could avoid JOINs altogether and still get `firstId`, `secondName` and `thirdName`:

```
SELECT *
FROM third
WHERE firstId = X
```

Even if there are other fields, not shown above, that you need to read from `second`, the JOIN will still be faster because InnoDB [clusters](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the data and you'd more naturally follow this clustering. And by avoiding surrogate keys, you'd avoid expensive secondary indexes (see "Disadvantages of clustering" in [this article](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/)).

The price you pay is in each successive child table growing progressively "fatter". Whether this is a price worth paying, only you can determine by performing measurements on representative amounts of data.

Comment: Of course i know that i break normalization mate :) as i mentioned, i was just thinking about performance implications, ignoring any design flaws (which are obvious in this case).